# How to update existing hive external table partition

Tags: hive, partition, external-tables

I have hive external table,  partitioned with year , month ,  day, hour. Now want to remove hourly partition, and have only year, month, day partitions, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: why do you need `day` if it is already `date`?

Comment: rearranging hive partition isnt possible online. You need to backup the data, drop and create the table with new partition structure and then copy data back from backup.

Comment: Hi leftjoin,  I have only day partition, edited my post.

Comment: Can you confirm your new partition strategy is  /yyyyMMdd/data-files
or /yyyy/MM/dd/data-files ?

Comment: Thank you Koushik Roy, I just took the backup, dropped existing table , created new table with required partitions and inserted data from backup.